# How to return a value from Column B, based on Column A data

Tags: google-sheets

So I want to try to return a value from Column B, when Column A has certain values. 
[image]

So for example here, when Column A is June, I'd like to return the value in Column B. (Or the average, or sum of them, etc). I've read through the GS documentation on functions and don't really see much as far as IF/THEN functions like this. Any Ideas?

Comment: Yes but just needed to remove the 'A' after select, it's just select avg(B). 

Also, didn't need the group by A - it returns the same result. What was the groupby supposed to do?

Comment: @I'-'I Solid, thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C1:

```
=QUERY(A:B,"Select A,avg(B) where A = 'June' group by A")
```

- avg() to sum() for SUM